# How to access process.env on Google App Engine with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm using react on google app engine.

As is written in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables

I can access the following Env Variable:

```
Environment variable    Description
GAE_APPLICATION The ID of your App Engine application.
GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID   The ID of the current deployment.
GAE_ENV The App Engine environment. Set to standard.
GAE_INSTANCE    The ID of the instance on which your service is currently running.
GAE_MEMORY_MB   The amount of memory available to the application process, in MB.
GAE_RUNTIME The runtime specified in your app.yaml file.
GAE_SERVICE The service name specified in your app.yaml file. If no service name is specified, it is set to default.
GAE_VERSION The current version label of your service.
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT    The GCP project ID associated with your application.
NODE_ENV    Set to production when your service is deployed.
PORT    The port that receives HTTP requests.
```

When I deploy my app on google app engine and print process.env console.log(process.env) I have only:

```
NODE_ENV: "production"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
```

In the documentation is explicitly written "The following environment variables are set by the runtime", but there are no one of them.

What is wrong?

Comment: I presume you are using the standard environment, right?

Comment: Nope, I'm using the flex environment

Comment: Then the list of environment variables is [this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables), the one you referenced is for the standard environment. Still, your question stands.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right documentation, but the environment variables are still the same two that I reported on the question.

Answer (score 0):

What it means by "The following environment variables are set by the runtime" is applicable to applications executed by `node`. As such, the `process.env` printed when ran from an express.js application contains those environment variables because you would be executing your code as `node .bin/www` or `node server.js` as opposed to `react-scripts start` when deploying a react.js application. In this case, it is create-react-app who has the responsibility in setting the environment variables. Alternatively, you can [manually set these environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) in accordance to the `create-react-app` specifications.

Comment: it's written in the documentation of google as I linked in the question. In google app engine the environment run in nodejs.

Comment: Yes, and it can actually be observed by deploying a basic [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) in App Engine and printing `process.env`. So in theory, since `create-react-app` uses `npm`, it is still technically using the nodejs runtime and as such should receive the environment variables set by GAE just like an expressjs app would. In reality, things are much more complicated. `create-react-app` relies on many `dependencies` such as Webpack, Babel, etc. and it could be that the configuration of `env` is dictated by one of those, having precedence over GAE.

Comment: so there is nothing to do?

Comment: From my findings, it simply isn't possible. `create-react-app` creates plenty of abstractions for the sake of simplicity and utility. For instance, there is not such thing as environment variables in the browser environment. `process.env` does not exist inside the browser environment; it is node.js-specific. Since it doesn't do server-side rendering, it cannot inject env variables during runtime. Instead, Webpack replaces all occurences of `process.env` with a string value **during build time**. In essence,  the env vars  from React is not the same from Node since it is simply an abstraction.

Comment: As such, this is more a limitation of the library, intended or not, than App Engine's fault. Subsequently, this issue would occur with any other Cloud Computing Service provider such as AWS or Heroku.