# Google App Engine: Setting environment variables for React Production Build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

I'm running a basic create-react-app production build on App Engine, but I'm not able to access my pre-defined environment variables. Is there any extra step I'm missing? I'm guessing it has something to do with the build process and serving a production build, but I'm not sure where to set the variable in this case.

app.yaml:

```
service: client-dev
runtime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  TEST: "development"
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "start-dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },


console.log(process.env.TEST) //undefined
```

Comment: I can not confirm if this is an issue happening on GAE or it just an issue on React side. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915758/node-process-env-variable-name-returning-undefined) with a similar issue and I also find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729098/how-to-access-process-env-on-google-app-engine-with-nodejs) on how to access process.env variables with GAE and Node.js. Nonetheless I will try to replicate the issue and see if there is any workaround or possible explanation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), environmental variables are embedded during build time in a React app. They will not be available to static files during runtime.

In App Engine, contents of **app.yaml** are used during deployment which happens after React has finished building.

To make environmental variables available during build time, you can:

1. include them in a **.env** file in the root of your project if you are manually triggering the build process via `yarn build` or `npm run build`.
2. include them in a **cloudbuild.yaml** file for automatic builds using a continuous development platform like [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine).

Note that the CRA documentation referenced above advises to begin every custom environment variable with `REACT_APP_`. For example your variable should be added like `REACT_APP_TEST=development`.